# Will Projects Started in VS 2010 & Finished in VS 2012 Cause End-User Issues Due to Dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I hope this question is suitable for this forum; I have a question regarding Visual Studio 2010 & Visual Studio 2012, which I have both and code up things in ASP.Net.

I understand that VS 2012 runs on the 4.5 .Net Framework, while VS 2010 runs on an earlier version. Also, I heard that if I coded something up originally in VS 2010, but say copy a project over to VS 2012, my application may have trouble running on an end-user's machine, if they are using an OS which is runs a lower version of the .Net Framework than the IDE I used to build/complete the application in question.

Thus, if I started a project in VS 2010, and finished the other 50% in VS 2012, would there been an issue with some of VS 2010's dependencies not being compatible in VS 2012's dependencies? Would this actually affect my end user?

Lastly, if I wanted to combat this issue (if it actually exists), could I just put the code for my pages in a text editor, and just transfer the code by hand to the IDE on the newer framework, and avoid a potential conflict between the two programs? I know I'll have a lot in terms of .aspx files, code-behind files, scripts and etc., but I don't feel building from scratch in VS 2012 just because end users will have a problem, as I started the project in an earlier program version. I hope I presented this where it makes some sense. Thanks.

Comment: Is this application actually running on the End user's machine? You have it tagged as `asp.net`, so it sounds like a web application. An end user does not need to host a web application on their machine.

Comment: Understood, because either I will be hosting it on a server or turn that over to a hosting service. I just wanted to know in case of an app that will run directly on the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not matter which version of visual studio you use to develop your application.  What matters is the targeted .Net Framework.  As long as the machine running it has .Net 4.5 you should be fine.

Comment: adding to this answer, if you start it in 2010 and target .NET 3.5, it should still also be targeted as .NET 3.5 in 2012 (or 2013) for that matter. It only matters what the targeted framework is set as when it's deployed.

Comment: Thanks! I see. If this is the case, then if I match up the framework on the newer IDE, you're saying I should have no client-side runtime issues, as I can simply copy over project files, and resume making additions, correct? 

And of course, I can simply have the client machine update the framework version on their side if they don't have it installed.

Comment: You shouldn't have to copy any files.  You should be able to open a VS2010 solution with VS2012 and it will convert everything for you.  Then you dont even have to matchup the framework version as it will already be in the solution properties.  Then as long as the machine hosting the ASP.Net project has the targeted version of the framework everything will be fine.